# How to convert a ODI interface into an SQL query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I am working on ODI 10 project which has 153 interfaces divided in a few packages. What I want to do is create a PL/SQL procedure with INSERT statements instead of having 153 interfaces. These interfaces are more or less similar i.e they have the same source table and same target (in my case target is a Essbase Hyperion cube), the transformations & filters are different. So anytime I have to update something like a column value , I have to open 153 interfaces and update in each and every one of them. In a procedure, I could do this so easily, I can just replace all values.

So I feel that its best that I create a PL/SQL procedure, as I can maintain the code better that way.

Is there a way to convert the interface into a SQL query?. I want a direct data dump, I don't want to do an complex incremental load. I am just looking to truncate the table and load the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to get the SQL code generated by ODI from the Operator in the log tables. It can also be retrieved in the repository.

Here is an example of a query for ODI 12c (10g being out of support for a long time now) :

```
SELECT s.sess_no, s.nno, step_name, scen_task_no, def_txt
  FROM SNP_SESS_STEP s, SNP_SESS_TASK_LOG t 
  WHERE s.sess_no = t.sess_no  
  AND s.nno = t.nno;
```

Starting with ODI 11g, it is also possible to simulate the execution instead of doing an actual execution. This functionality will just display the code generated in ODI Studio instead of running it.

Finally, upgrading to a more recent of ODI would allow to use the ODI SDK. With it you could programmatically do changes to all the mappings in one go. Reusable mappings could also help as it sounds that some logic is implemented multiple times. That would enable to ease these kind of changes while keeping the benefits of an ELT tool (scheduling, monitoring, visual representation of flows, cross-technology, ...).

Disclaimer : I'm an Oracle employee

Comment: Thanks a ton! I will push my company to upgrade the 10g to 12c. Looks like we are missing out on a LOT of new features of ODI. I just joined this company and this is the first time I'm working with ODI.